# 18 word mnemonic seed that contains words outside of BIP39 wordlist, struggling to recover BTC

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, recover-private-key

I recently recovered a document containing information relating to some BTC I purchased in 2015. I only have: a passphrase/password, an 18 word mnemonic phrase(the majority of which are not in the BIP39 wordlist, nor the electrum old/new wordlists, e.g. mccartney, hopkinton), and the address: 1CfadqyBDRPt62S9UvBHDPtqRu2kSvwPPu.
I idiotically forgot to add what wallet I used, so I'm a bit stuck.

Any ideas about what the mnemonic could be for?

Comment: Answering these kinds of questions are rarely ever free.

Comment: I understand, I  was just wondering if someone else had encountered a similar issue in the past.

Comment: That’s a blockchain.info “recovery phrase”, which isn’t a seed and isn’t enough to recover your wallet.

Comment: Remember the 1st four characters of the BIP39 seed words need to remain unchanged to identify what the real BIP 39 seed words are.  If this gets you nowhere, read the BIP 39 Standard as to how seed words are used to synthesize entropy.  You will note that the entropy associated with different spoken languages leads to wildly different results.  Understanding that the effective sha512 hashing a the seed words might provide insights what happens when seed words are misspelled or improperly recorded. However, taking this approach will be  very implementation specific.

Comment: it is your waled ID and password for blockchain.com in encrypted format. should be enough to recover your funds.