# How to restore my Bitcoin Core wallet from seed phrase

Tags: wallet, seed, passphrase

I have my Bitcoin Core wallet protected with passphrase for a long time ago. Now I'm trying to move out the coin from there but unfortunately I forgot the passphrase. When finding for recovery info I only found the list of seed phrases assigned to this wallet.

Is there anyway I can recover my wallet with seed phrase only? Thank you very much in advance for any advice.

Comment: This seems unlikely - bitcoin core uses seeds, but not seed phrases - do you have a list of actual english words, or just a random string of characters?

Comment: It's a list of 18 words. Actually it's secrets word from where I download app: bitsblock.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin Core is not affiliated with the website you downloaded the node installer from - bitsblock.io, and the official Bitcoin Core client does not provide functionality you ask about. I noticed that when you click on download button on this website it takes you to some restore form. This seems very sketchy - I'd never provide online my private key nor any other means to derive it (such as list of backup codes, phrases, passwords, etc.). Try looking for legit wallet that supports BIP39, I cannot vouch for that but supposedly Electrum wallet does that. Also, as mentioned [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/86025/18-word-mnemonic-seed-that-contains-words-outside-of-bip39-wordlist-struggling), it might be actually a restore phrase for blockchain.info online wallet (though as mentioned earlier, I would discourage entering recovery phrases on any website).

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core does not, and has never used seed phrases. Its likely you’re not recalling the correct software or procedure here.

Comment: Actually it's from bitsblock.io. I created my wallet from there and it gave me a list of seed words. The app downloaded from bitsblock.io is 100% the same as Bitcoin core.

Comment: In 2017 bitcoin core wallet offered a seed phrase upon creating a wallet and suggested if the wallet is deleted or you forget the passphrase you could recover your wallet with the seed phrase.

Comment: No version of Bitcoin Core, at any time, has offered seed phrases for recovery.

Comment: In 2017 bitcoin core offered a 12 phrase BIP39 mnemonic for wallet recovery

Comment: You are simply incorrect, this has never even been a proposed feature for any release.

Comment: You are correct, It appears that I mistook bitcoin.com wallet for bitcoin core.

Answer (score 0):

The bitcoin core passphrase encrypts the wallet, so in my experience, you won't be able to recover this private key.

Comment: So I understand that I totally lost my BTC?

Comment: You can try to guess some password you entered when you created the wallet, run some brute force algorithm to try to guess the password, but I can't see any other solution than that.