# I have Bitcoin core v 23.0 I have my 12 word seed how do I recover my wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed

I have Bitcoin core version 23.0 I have my
12 word seed how do I recover my wallet?

Comment: Bitcoin Core does not use or support 12-word seed phrases (or any seed phrases), so it's unclear what these things have to do with each other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore my Bitcoin Core wallet from seed phrase](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92745/how-to-restore-my-bitcoin-core-wallet-from-seed-phrase)

Comment: Which blockchain app do you make use of?

Answer (score 3):

With a cold wallet or a hot wallet that supports BIP39 you should be able to restore your account using your 12-word seed. After you restore your account, you can send your coins to your Bitcoin Core address.

Note: Bitcoin Core itself does not support seed words.

Comment: This! Bitcoin Core doesn't use seed phrases.